# Backend produced unparsable log entry

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Backend produced unparsable log entry
{"msg":"enqueueNode","enqueuedNodeAnnotation":"CopyFiles Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp.dll","enqueuedNodeIndex":385,"enqueueingNodeAnnotation":"Scrip

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.
I think this error occurred when my project was opening in unity editor. I forced it to shut.
To solve the error:

1. Navigate to the project root folder in the file manager.
2. Delete Library folder(By deleting this you may have to reimport your packages again)

**Note** : After following the above steps, when you open a project in unity editor again, you may see that all your scenes are gone (happened to me), but actually, the scenes are not gone. Unity created a new scene by default. To open your scene, you have to navigate to the scene's folder and open the scene from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to leave a comment so I'll have to post it as an answer.

I received this exact error after cloning a Unity Project onto my local machine from GitHub. As RBT suggested, the problem was solved by deleting the Library folder in my file directly and reopening the project through Unity Hub. It took time for the project to (re)load data into a newly generated Library folder but afterwards the error disappeared and I was able to test the game without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the Bee Folder will fix this issue

- 1> **Close the game project**
- 2> Go to Folder **"GameProjectName" > "Library"**
- 3> Delete the **"Bee"** Folder
- 4> **Open the project again** in Unity

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I worked on **MacOS** and **Unity 2021.3.14.**
I fixed it finding that my XCode had a new update and accepted the new XCode license.
But before I did some other steps too. That also can be the solution or part of them. I'm not sure. So I leave here all the steps that I did.

1. I upgraded the **Firebase** from v10.6.0 to 10.7.0.
2. Then force resolved the Android dependencies.
3. Closed the Unity and reopen.
4. Noticed that some unity packages from git (**NSubstitute, FluentAssertions**)had errors and needed me to accept the new XCode license update. I agreed with the new license agreement and then I didn't get that error anymore.